# Can I split the speed of a single ISP (and a single source) into two routers, so their speeds don't depend on the internet consumption of each other?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

First I'd like to say I'm an absolute newbie in network configuration or anything related, by newbie I mean really newbie.

The problem is that my Internet is quite slow (8mbps download, 1 mbps upload), and therefore when someone starts watching video streaming, sensible data such as gaming data is hugely affected.

My doubt is if I'd be able to split the speed of the service provided between 2 routers (and therefore 2 signals/networks), so each one gets 4mbps and their speeds don't depend at all on the  speed of each other, in a way that if one uses its 4mbps maximum, it won't consume the speed of the other router.

Right now I have a thomson dwg855tlg rca modem, but I will willingly buy any devices needed for this to happen.

Basically I'd like to know what I need to buy and how I should configure (physically and virtually) step by step (in simple words as I don't understand networking terms at all).
Thank you.

NOTE: I'm not really looking for an answer involving QoS or limiting bandwidth for devices connected to the network, but trying to find out if I can split an internet service coming from my ISP into 2 different network which don't depend on each other in terms of speed.

Comment: You need a router that supports Quality of Service (QOS) controls. There are lots of them out there.

Comment: You can't split a single Internet connection into two separate networks. There's only one network between you and your ISP, and it can't be split. However, you can get the results you want from QoS controls, which is why that's what people are suggesting.

Comment: @MikeScott: A network can be split easily. The fact that a router allows more than one device to connect means it's already splitting it.

Comment: To split the speed between two routers, you need... a speed splitting router. If your router is already capable of it, then you have no need to split the speed between two routers. Kinda counter-productive. All you want it to split the speed between two people or devices.

Answer (score 3):

Look at purchasing a router with QoS (Quality of Service).
I'm assuming that your gaming is being interrupted when someone is streaming?

If that is the case then you need to identify which ports you will be prioritising. Most models allow you to set minimum bandwidth of QoS traffic so you can set 4MBPS as your minimum. Also have a look at https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database and find a router on that database it will open up a lot of options for you in regards to traffic shaping.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't really looking for an answer involving QoS or limiting bandwidth for devices connected to the network, but trying to find out if I can split an internet service coming from my ISP into 2 different network which don't depend on each other in terms of speed. Thank you anyways, I'll investigate QoS options as well.

Comment: @Fernando, all "splitting" would do is limit each connection at 4Mbps, those are exactly the kind of controls QoS handles.

Comment: And could I use this QoS to limit bandwidth taken by both of the routers, or I can only limit the bandwidth used by for example my computer. Could you give me the name of a router that provides this kind of characteristics?

Comment: By focusing on the splitting you have no control over the actual choke point so you don't throttle either network or allow any to just use half of the bandwidth. By using QoS you can guarantee a minimum amount of speed you require for a certain service (e.g. gaming or streaming).